# How to obtain saturated pressure of water at 200 ºC using fugacities?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

The target is to obtain saturated pressure of water at $\pu{200 ^\circ C}$ using PHI-PHI (fugacity coefficients) approach, so it means it's a VLE  of water only, so we write equilibrium condition:

$$f_i(l) = f_i(v),\tag1\label1$$

with $f_i(l)/P=PHI(l)$ and the same for $PHI(v)$ (note that $Y_i=X_i=1$), substituting into \eqref{1} we get:

$$PHI(l)=PHI(v)$$

There are several ways to calculate $PHI$ and here we use the RK equation of state, my problem begins here, if we calculate the $PHI$, then what should we do next? Don't we need $f_i$ to calculate $P$?

Comment: Are you talking about $\phi(l)$, maybe $\varphi(l)$? What is a PHI-PHI approach? What does VLE stand for? Where did $X_i$ and $Y_i$ come from? What is $(*)$? What is RK equation of state? What is $P$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea, for whatever it's worth.  For a real material like water, if you plot pressure as a function of decreasing specific volume at any temperature below the critical temperature, the graph will become perfectly flat in the two-phase region (where you have a combination of liquid and vapor).  It will then start to rise again once the specific volume reaches that of the liquid.  In the case of an equation of state like RK, this won't happen.  The graph will be smooth, and will exhibit maxima and minima in the two phase region.  I know that $\mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}P$ at constant $T$, so, if I integrate from a large specific volume downward at constant temperature, I should be able to produce the curve of $G$ vs $V$ (and $p$) for an arbitrary equation of state. At constant $T$, we have:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T
= -\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_p
   \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V
$$

The first parenthesis on the right is, of course, equal to zero for a real substance in the two-phase region.  If I substitute this into the equation for $\mathrm{d}G$, I get:
$$
\mathrm{d}G
= -V\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_p
    \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V\mathrm{d}V
$$

So, I can integrate this equation downward from high specific volumes (where the ideal gas law applies) through the "two-phase" region of an equation of state.  If I plot a graph of $G$ vs $V$, I can see the points where the values of $G$ are the same and the values of $p$ are also the same.  This should identify the saturated values of the liquid and vapor specific volumes and pressure.  Maybe that's what your equations already do.

Comment: Actually setting fugacity coefficients equal to each other is an direct result of no change in G and the equality of values ,We used the same concept by different ways, It was a great approach sir,Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me involved.  It was a very interesting and challenging problem.

Comment: Hi, would you be willing to help edit the question to tidy up a bit of the notation? I will readily admit that I don't know anything about the topic - but ideally readers, even those who don't know much, shouldn't have to try to decipher abbreviations / notations. I've tried asking the user base more generally, but I couldn't find anybody with the necessary knowledge, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

We know that fugacity coefficients must be equal, so taking a natural log we have:

$$\ln PHI(l) = \ln PHI(v)$$

As we know in thermodynamics (better to refer Chem. Eng. Thermodynamics by J.Smith):

$$\ln PHI = Z -1 -\ln(Z-\beta)-q \cdot I,$$

Which $\beta=b\cdot \frac{P}{RT}$ and $b$ is an EoS parameter like $q$, about $I$ for $RK$ EoS it is:

$$I=\ln\frac{Z+\beta}{Z}$$

As we see all of them depend on $P$ which is we want, this was the confusing thing for me, note $Z$ and $I$ are different for vapor and liquid,
and we have some correlations for $Z_v$ and $Z_l$ so we can obtain $I_i$ and $I_v$:

\begin{align}
Z_v &= 1+\beta - q\cdot \beta\frac{Z_v-\beta}{Z_v\cdot(Z_v+\beta)}\\
Z_l &= \beta+Z_l \cdot (Z_l+\beta)\frac{1+\beta-Z_l}{q\cdot\beta}
\end{align}

We use top equations for $PHI_v$ and $PHI_l$ in respect,
so we have non-linear multi variate system of equations, for $I_v$, $I_l$, $Z_v$, $Z_l$ and $P$.

Here is the code for solving:

```
function F = root2d(x)

F(1) = x(1)-5.3726e-04*x(5)-x(1)*(x(1)+5.3726e-04*x(5))*(1+5.3726e-04*x(5)-x(1))/0.0042*x(5);
F(2) = x(2)-1-5.3726e-04*x(5)+7.8914*5.3726e-04*x(5)*((x(2)-5.3726e-04*x(5))/(x(2)*(x(2)+5.3726e-04*x(5))));

F(3) = x(3)-log((x(1)+5.3726e-04*x(5))/x(1));

F(4) = x(4)-log((x(2)+5.3726e-04*x(5))/x(2))

F(5) = x(2)-log(x(2)-5.3726e-04*x(5))-7.8914*x(4)-x(1)+log(x(1)-5.3726e-04*x(5))+7.8914*x(3);
```

And the solving code:

```
options = optimset('MaxIter',500,'MaxFunEvals',500);

fun = @root2d;
x0 = [0.1,0.9,0.5,0.5,15];
x = fsolve(fun,x0,options);
```

$x(1)$ to $x(5)$ are $Z_l$, $Z_v$, $I_l$, $I_v$, $P$.

The answer we get is:

```
x =

0.0112    0.9348    0.6543    0.0753   15.5033
```

In which the $P$ is very near to the steam table value (15.54 bar).

Comment: It looks like you were able to solve it correctly.  I am not familiar with the equations you used, so I have trouble relating to what you did.  The method I suggested in my original answer is obviously not the way to go, so I have deleted my answer.  But I have developed an alternative approach that I'm pretty confident will work.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I'll appreciate it if you share your way with me,I'll learn a new way...thank you.